# Mysql (php) update or replace shopping bag content in one query, with multiple values

Tags: mysql, replace

I've got the flowing tables in mysql db for a shopping bag:

```
BAGS
-----
| bagID         | date_added |         
| primary Key   |            |
------------------------------
| 1             | 2012-01-04 |

BAGS_CONTENT
-----
| ID                  | productID | qyt |
| foreign key->bagID  |           |     |
-----------------------------------------
| 1                   |    103    |  4  |

// $sql Could contain this:

$sql = "(1,103,5),
       (1,101,3)";

INSERT INTO BAGS_CONTENT 
( ID, product_id, qty) 
VALUES
".$sql."
```

I like the `BAGS_CONTENT` to update an existing record (if exists `ID` and `product_id`) and add a new row if not exists (the `ID` and `product_id`).

I've tried using `REPLACE INTO` and `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but I can't get it to work.

May be its has something to do with the keys?
How should you query the db in a situation like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE triggers the UPDATE statement when the unique value is already existing in the table. Make sure that you've set the right fields to be unique. I think you have to put an *UNIQUE* on `ID` and `productID` (both in one combined unique):
`ALTER TABLE BAGS_CONTENT ADD UNIQUE (ID, product_id)`

Your query should look like this:
`INSERT INTO BAGS_CONTENT (ID, product_id, qty) ".$sql." ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE qty = VALUES(qty);`

Here's more information about 'on duplicate key':
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Thank you've almost gave the same answer (Ray and Eugen Rieck) and it solves the problem. (I'm still learning).

Answer (score 1):

To use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` you first need to create a unique key on BAGS_CONTENT(ID,productID)

Then use

```
INSERT INTO BAGS_CONTENT (ID,productID,qyt) VALUES(1,101,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE qyt=VALUES(qyt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a key *error* in order to trigger the special behavior of REPLACE.  To get the proposed behavior add an index:

```
mysql> create table bag_content (id INT,productID INT,qty SMALLINT);
mysql> create unique index baggy on bag_content (id,productID);
mysql> replace bag_content values(1,111,5);
mysql> replace bag_content values(1,112,5);
mysql> replace bag_content values(1,111,500);
mysql> select * from bag_content;
+------+-----------+------+
| id   | productID | qty  |
+------+-----------+------+
|    1 |       111 |  500 |
|    1 |       112 |    5 |
+------+-----------+------+
```

Also watch out: you're using SQL supported in mysql only. The pejorative is 'their sql'... because of all the innovations of mysql that don't go through a standards process.  The replace functionality is great, but it will increase the barrier to moving your code to other databases.